# How to convert sdf to excel?

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server-ce

How do I convert all the data (tables) of a SQL Server CE `.sdf` file to xls or xlsx using C#?

I want to do some checking on the data of the database and I do not want to directly modify the database.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

[How to use an SDF in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/811432/Use-Local-DataBase-file-sdf-in-Windows-Application)

[How to use Excel in C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm)

Use some tape and bind the two together. Just kidding. Read through the two, they should provide the answer.